# graphql - Add items to `errors` array while still returning data

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm writing a graphQL API using Apollo server and I would like to know is there a way to add an error to the `errors` array returned in the response, without throwing an actual error and failing the entire resolver.

In my code I iterate an input array and in case I encounter an unsupported item, I wish to add it to the `errors` array returned in the response, while still returning data for the other valid items.

Please advise if and how I can do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for 'partial data', 'multiple errors' ... or ... save errors in some context object,, format them as errors on middleware/hook

Comment: if I format then in a different function, how to add them to the `errors` array? just throw them?